# How to get the value of an input dynamically

Tags: javascript

Currently I am storing the values of the text inputs and selects from a table in the `options` variable.

```
var options = $(tbody).find("select option:selected").map( (_, e) => $(e).text().trim() ).get();
var msgs = $(tbody).find("input[type='text']").map( (_, e) => $(e).val().trim() ).get();
options.splice(2, 0, msgs[0]);
options.splice(4, 0, msgs[1]);
```

The thing is, for selects, in addition to the text, I would also like to know the value.

I'd like to get it with something like: `options[5].val;` But obviously it doesn't work.

What is the most typical/correct JavaScript way of achieving a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way : with the help of **selectedOptions**

```js
const mySelect = document.querySelector('select[name="my-select"]')

mySelect.onchange = () =>
  {
  console.clear()
  Array.from(mySelect.selectedOptions)
    .forEach(opt => { console.log(opt.value, opt.textContent ) })
  }
```

```css
select { 
  margin : 1em;
  width  : 7em; 
  text-align: center;
  }
  
  /***/
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:70% !important; width:30%; }
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<select name="my-select" size="8"  multiple >
  <option value="a"> aaaaa </option>
  <option value="b"> bbbbb </option>
  <option value="c"> ccccc </option>
  <option value="d"> ddddd </option>
  <option value="e"> eeeee </option>
  <option value="f"> fffff </option>
  <option value="g"> ggggg </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if we don't know the id or name of the select (my case). And the event onchange is not relevant in this case, since I'm getting a table via function parameter, which means the selects have already been selected. The event will never fire.

Comment: @Cheknov the addition of the `onchange` is only there to illustrate the answer, the use of the `selectedOptions` remains valid with or without ;)